# Saltstack - Jinja template always gets default value instead of pillar value

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

(First, please note, I am calling my app's "worker" a "minion", since I prefer the master/minion convention to other choices.  I am not specifically talking about a *Salt minion* in my states, etc below)

I have used Saltstack for a long time, but I never really dipped my toes into custom formulas.  I am trying that now and I am running into an issue I don't understand.  It may or may not be related to being a formula (I tend to think not).

My set up is as follows:

```
app-formula      # root directory for formula
  app/
  app/minion.sls # state which installs packages and configuration
  app/defaults.yaml 
  app/minion/config.json # Jinja2 template for a json configuration file
```

As you can see, this is a fairly basic setup.  I have a state called app.minion that installs packages and configuration.  The app/minion/config.json file is a Jinja template.  I am having problems with it specifically.

In particular, the json file starts like:

```
{% import_yaml "app/defaults.yaml" as defaults %}
{% set minion = salt.pillar.get( 'app.minion', default=defaults.app.minion, merge=true %}

{
  "rpc-username": {{ minion.app.rpc.username }}
}
```

As you can see, the template is supposed to go to the pillar `app.minion` to get the `app.rpc.username` value.

The problem is that when the Jinja template is run, Jinja or Salt apparently cannot find the pillar value, so it fills in the default value.

I am fairly sure my pillar value is fine, though.  My pillar structure is like:

```
salt/
  pillars/
    app/minion.sls # file contains:
      'app.minion':
         app:
           rpc:
             username: foo
```

I can confirm that salt finds the pillar when I call `sudo salt-call pillar.get 'app.minion'`, which works fine and returns the nested structure I expect.

Comment: Use e.g. `salt["log.info"]` to inspect the value of `minion`, and of `salt["pillar.get"]("app.minion")`.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Thanks so much for helping.  Changing to `salt["pillar.get"]` did not resolve my problem with always getting the default value.  Can you expand what you mean by using `salt["log.info"]`?  Do you mean in a template to try to debug this issue?  Or in some other environment?  I'll read the docs for `log.info` next.

Comment: Yes, to debug the issue. So you can see what it's actually returning, and what the merged result is.